# How to make a mulitlingual website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, multilingual

I am an amateur programmer and I want to make a mulitlingual website. My questions are: (For my purposes let the English website be website nr 1 and the Polish nr 2)

1. Should it be en.example.com and pl.example.com or maybe example.com/en and example.com/pl?
2. Should I make the full website in one language and then translate it?
3. How to translate it? Using XML or what? Should website 1 and website 2 be different html files or is there a way to translate a html file and then show the translation using XML or something?

If You need any code or something tell me. Thank You in advance :)

Comment: You can try to use [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)

Comment: You really have three separate questions here. 1 is opinion based and off topic. 2 is also opinion based and off topic. 3 could be considered opinion based or too broad, but is off topic in either case.

Comment: I would suggest looking at templates, something like Smarty or equivalent. This would mean you would make a  website once and then simply work on labels that are translated into different languages and chosen via user settings, cookies or session data.

Comment: I would suggest `example.com/en` and `example.com/pl`, if you want them in the same domain. You should use templates for your view and separate language files, which can be also XML or XLIFF. So you would have just one file for the start page, inside you have `{{ startpage.title }}`. In your language files you have translation for that ID: `startpage.title: This is my page`, and do the same for the Polish translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I don't think it makes much difference. The most important thing is to ensure that Google can crawl both languages, so don't rely on JavaScript to switch between languages, have everything done server side so both languages can be crawled and ranked in Google.

2) You can do one translation then the other, you just have to ensure that the layout expands to accommodate more/less text without breaking it. Maybe use lorem ipsum whilst designing.

3) I would put the translations into a database and then call that particular translation depending on whether it is EN or PL in the domain name. Ensure that the webpage and database are UTF-8 encoding otherwise you will find that you get 'funny' characters being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

My Advice is that you start to use any Framework.

For instance if you use CakePHP then you have to write

```
__('My name is')
```

and in translate file

```
msgid "My name is"
msgstr "Nazywam się"
```

Then you can easy translate to any other language and its pretty easy to implement.

Also if you do not want to use Framework you can check this link to see example how it works:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/12/30/easy-php-site-translation/

Answer (score 0):

While this question probably is not a good SO question due to its broad nature. It might be relevant to many users.

My approach would be templates.
Your suggestion of having two html files is bad for the obvious reason of duplication- say you need to change something in your site. You would always need to change two html files- bad.

Having one html file and then parsing it and translating it sounds like a massive headache.

Some templating framework could help you massively. I have been using Smarty, but that's a personal choice and there are many options here.

The idea is you make a template file for your html and instead of actual content you use labels. Then in your php code you include the correct language depending on cookies, user settings or session data.

Storing labels is another issue here. Storing them in a database is a good option, however, remember you do not wish to make 100's of queries against a database for fetching each label. What you can do is store them in a database and then have it generate a language file- an array of labels->translations for faster access and regenerate these files whenever you add/update labels.

Or you can skip the database altogether and just store them in files, however, as these grow they might not be as easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest mistake for an "amateur programmer" to make in this area is to allow the two (or more) language versions of the site to diverge. (I've seen so-called professionals make that mistake too...) You need to design it so everything that's common between the two versions is shared, so that when the time comes to make changes, you only need to make the changes in one place. The way you do this will depend on your choice of tools, and I'm not going to start advising on that, because it depends on many factors, for example the extent to which your content is database-oriented.

Closely related to this are questions of who is doing the translation, how the technical developers and the translators work together, and how to keep track of which content needs to be re-translated when it changes. These are essentially process questions rather than coding questions, so not a good fit for SO.

Don't expect that a site for one language can be translated without any technical impact; you will find you have made all sorts of assumptions about the length of strings, the order of fields, about character coding and fonts, and about cultural things like postcodes, that turn out to be invalid when you try to convert the site to a different language.

Answer (score -1):

You could make 2 different language files and use php constants to define the text you want to translate for example:

```
lang_pl.php:
define("_TEST", "polish translation");

 lang_en.php:
 define("_TEST", "English translation");
```

now you could make a choice for the user between polish or english translation and based on that you can include the language file.

So if you would have a text field you put its value to _TEST (inbetween php brackets).

and it would show the translation of the chosen option.

Answer (score -1):

The place i worked was doing it like this: they didn't have to much writing on their site, so they were keeping it in a database. As your tags have a php , I assume you know how to use databases. They had a mysql table called languages with language id(in your case 1 for en and 2 for pl) and texts in columns. So the column names were main heading, intro_text, about_us... when the user comes it selects the language and a php request get the page with that language. This is easy because your content is static and can be translated before site gets online, if your content is dynamic(users add content) you may need to use a translation machine because you cannot expect your users to write their entry in all languages.